# Difference in Executable Size in C89 and C99 standards

Tags: c, size, nm

I made an Executable using GCC

```
$ gcc Q1.c -save-temps -std=c89 -o Q1
$ size Q1
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1509        264       8    1781     6f5 Q1
```

and then i do this

```
$ gcc Q1.c -save-temps -std=c99 -o Q1
$ size Q1
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1544        264       8    1816     718 Q1
```

What might have caused a differrence in the **text size** of the program, what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: The standard clearly requires C99 compilers to produce bigger executables than their C89 equivalent.

Comment: any specific reason for that?

Comment: It would also be interesting to see this under different compilers/compiled to different architectures. It might just be the optimiser in the GCC compiler that's written differently for different standards - and therefore this is compiler specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific reason. Maybe different optimizations due to stricter standard. On my computer:

```
-> % gcc test.c -save-temps -std=c89
-> % size a.out 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1093     568       8    1669     685 a.out
-> % gcc test.c -save-temps -std=c99 
-> % size a.out                     
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1093     568       8    1669     685 a.out
```

This is highly empirical. Maybe using `-O` flags even changes the results.

Comment: Tried the same thing.. but my output was different from your's i still got larger file size in C99 Standard. Maybe it has to do with the program we are compiling. I Shall try this with a simple "Hell World" program and update you with result.

Comment: Seriously, the answer is that there is no rationale behind the difference.